# Automatically add/scan existing cover art in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

I built my Banshee DB from scratch and am now facing the issue, that none of my albums shows cover art unless I start playing one of its songs. All the album folders contain a cover file *cover.jpg* and I don't want anything to be downloaded from the internet.

I guess one workaround would be to play one song from each album for one second and then skip to the next via the remote control functionality of Banshee but that seems rather cumbersome.

Is there already a way to trigger this cover art scan from within Banshee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647898) which is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Banshee maintainer Bertrand Lorentz's [post on the mailing list](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-make-Banshee-2-0-or-later-resume-downloading-Album-Cover-Art-tp3734955p3750898.html):

> With banshee 2.1.0 or later, you can tell banshee to fetch all cover 
>   art by adding the --fetch-artwork command line option. 
>   Just quit Banshee and type the following in a terminal :
>
> ```
> banshee --fetch-artwork
> ```

I would assume this batch artwork gathering should follow the same order of priorities as normal, so *cover.jpg* should be looked at before searching the internet for artwork. If you want to be extra sure, you could temporarily check the "Disable features requiring Internet access" box in Banshee's Edit > Preferences.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work and seems to only affect media art fetched via the internet (getting a startup message "Reset CoverArtDownloads table so missing artwork will get fetched").